# Detect touch on Cell of UITableView contained in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, touch

I am creating a Chinese learning app, with a section for correctly pronouncing certain sounds. To organise these sounds into a table, I have created a `UICollectionView`, where each `UICollectionViewCell` contains a `UITableView`.

Each `UICollectionViewCell` acts as a column, and contains a `UITableView`.

Each `UITableViewCell` acts as a row in each column.

This results in the following appearance.

[image: UICollectionView containing UITableViews]

However, although I can easily detect taps on each `UICollectionViewCell` using `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` , I am unable to detect any touches at all on the `UITableViewCell`s within.

Whether I convert the view in the Cell to be a button, or whether I as a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, or whether I use the function `tableView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, no touches at all are detected in the `UITableView`.

How can I allow my code to correctly detect these touches on the `UITableViewCell`s within the `UICollectionView`?

Thanks!

**Update 1:**

Here is the @interfact of the Column .h file (UICollectionViewCell)

```
@interface PronounciationColumn : UICollectionViewCell <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

In the .m of the UICollectionViewCell, the delegate and dataSource of the tableView is set to self.

**Update 2:**

Another user had a really neat idea of setting the delegate of the tableView to it's own collectionViewCell using the following code:

```
- (PronounciationColumn *)collectionView:(nonnull UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PronounciationColumn *column;
    NSString *columnIdentifier = [self getIdentifier:collectionView];
    if (column == nil) {
        column = (PronounciationColumn *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:columnIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        column.arrayOfFinals = [[self getArrayOfPinyins:collectionView] objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    }
    column.tableOfFinals.delegate = column;
    column.tableOfFinals.dataSource = column;
    return column;
}
```

The tableView continues to be populated correctly, however, the touches are still not detected on the cells, as `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is still not called.

Comment: Did you set delegate and datasource of tableViews to each cell?

Comment: I'm unsure. I updated the question with some more information of what I set the delegate and dataSource to.

Comment: you should set delegate and datasource of each tableView to its collectionViewCell in `cellForRowAt` method of `collectionView`

Comment: I've added a second update to my question based on your advice :)

Comment: I added a third update! The tableView now correctly populates, but tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is still not yet called.

Comment: os this on ios 13?

Comment: It is, yeah. I'm running the app on an iPhone 8 Simulator which is running iOS 13.1

Comment: This seems to be a classic case of subviews not being able to have their touches detected in iOS. It seems like this occurs for many people, and the only solutions are usually hack overrides of functions.

Comment: i nest 3-4 collection views inside another collection view all the time and never had an experience like this. is there a reason why you're nesting a UITableView and not just nesting another UICollectionView? UITableViews are absolute trash. I'd change it to a UICollectionView that is nested inside the other UICollectionVeiw first and then reassss.

Comment: I ended up just programatically coding my table-collectionview by having UIViews within UIViews to act as columns and rows, and calculating their positions using for-loops iterating through my array of array of data. I'm leaving this question open for other people to offer potential solutions for people to try should they also come up with this challenge. Yours does sound elegant, I would have tried it if I had heard of it sooner!